# How do I disable automatic cursor placement in web browsers?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer-8

Well, pretty much my question is the title. I use Google Chrome, Chromium, Firefox, and Internet Explorer 8 and was wondering how I could disable the automatic cursor placement when accessing different websites. I'm still a bit faster than all the browsers when typing in my usernames and passwords (which is really the reason why I'm asking) and it never fails that I'll see my username enter in fine, then a couple of characters from my password, then my cursor will jump back up to the username field and plug in half of my password there and fail to login of course after I hit the enter key. Mind you, I'm usually typing in the user/pass and hitting enter afterwards fairly quick, so its not like I'm meaning to do this.

Also, it would help whenever I open up my home page (which is google) and want to type in a new URL. Even google has it where the cursor will automatically jump to the search box after a few seconds, so I'll end up searching google for half of the URL I was trying to type in the address bar.

I searched on google and here for a solution already, but didn't see an apparent one in the first couple of pages, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution for Firefox:

1. Type the following into the Firefox address bar: `about:config`
2. Right-click on any value and select `New > String`
3. You will first be prompted for the preference name. Enter the following: `capability.policy.default.HTMLInputElement.focus`
4. Next, you will be prompted for the preference value. Enter the following: `noAccess`

That's it!

If you're not happy with the change, undoing it is a little more complicated:

1. Close Firefox if it's open by going into the `File` menu and choosing `Exit`.
2. Locate your Application Data folder. The easiest way to do this is to go to the Start menu, choose Run, and type in "`%APPDATA%`" (without the quotes.)
3. Navigate to your profile folder. It should be in `Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/_____.default`, where the underscore is a string of random characters. Find the file called `prefs.js` and open it in a text editor, such as Notepad. (Do not just double-click it. You should be able to right-click it and choose `Edit` from the context menu.)
4. Search for the line that contains `capability.policy.default.HTMLInputElement.focus`. It will look like this in its entirety:
   `user_pref("capability.policy.default.HTMLInputElement.focus", "noAccess");`
5. Delete this line, and only this line. Save the file. You may now restart Firefox.

Comment: This is a great answer, I wonder if you could edit it and update it for The new versions of firefox because I couldn't find the preference `capability.policy.default.HTMLInputElement.focus`.

Answer (score 1):

When the page is loaded, or even half-loaded, and you're ready to go, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> or stop the browser from loading the rest of the page.

The behaviour you're seeing when you type in one input and then it jumps to another is because the JavaScript has finished loading and carrying out it's little focus script.

The JavaScript loaded with the pages is setting the focus on an element and often disregards how much you've typed, or if you've typed at all, before defaulting to the input field of choice.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't realize that it was the javascript in the page that was causing this since it happens on so many different sites that I visit regularly. Is there a way to disable this element focusing in my JRE or specifically in each web browser?

Thanks again,

Justin

Comment: Not really. Not unless you disable JavaScript entirely. But then it would probably break most of the site if you do.

Comment: JRE ?? Javascript IS NOT Java

Comment: I wonder what else will stop working when stopping JavaScript. There's a lot of sites out there that depend on jQuery and the like to layout the content, or on Ajax to dynamically load data.

Comment: Sometimes you have to grin and bear the autofocus on a field if you want a site to play nicely and all whiz bangy.

Comment: With Firefox, you could try the add-on NoScript and see for yourself if/how functionality is reduced on the sites you use. Then you can re-enable JavaScript on a site-per-site basis.

Comment: Thanks for the other comments. I was primarily concerned with Chrome/Chromium as I do have NoScipt and Adblock installed for Firefox (which I rarely use anymore). I appreciate the original ESC tip.

Answer (score 0):

As you even encounter this "*after a few seconds*" at the very light page of google.com (today 13.44 KB in total, 3 KB when cache is used), I'd search for a way to make the pages load faster. The Google home page should be on your screen instantly.

I assume you did not disable caching? Do you have a lot of add-ons installed? Maybe some hyperactive virus scanner? Or some malware that needs time to spy on you?

If it's the internet connection: maybe your provider has some caching proxy server for you?

Or, if the computer is slow: disable Google Analytics and other tracking scripts by installing [Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/).

(Just to avoid your password is shown in the username field: use a password manager rather than typing the credentials yourself.)

Comment: Google's autofocus has slowed down a *lot* since they introduced the suggestions. I blocked clients1.google.com and it's a lot faster for me now (though I can't promise that won't break any other apps).

Comment: To disable Google Suggest see http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/08/google-suggest-enabled-by-default.html

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox install the Greasemonkey addon then use the user script called [Unfocuser](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/89702).